# How to insert a number sequence in Emacs with multiple cursors?

Tags: emacs

How can I insert a number sequence with the [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) package in Emacs?

For example:

```
aa|    aa1
aa| => aa2
aa|    aa3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `M-x mc/insert-numbers`.  By default, it inserts `0` for the first cursor, `1` for the second cursor etc, but you can change this by using a numeric prefix argument.  So to get 1, 2, 3 as in your example, use `C-u 1 M-x mc/insert-numbers`.

Comment: or add `(setq mc/insert-numbers-default 1)` to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file

Comment: I've bound that to `C-c n` with `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'mc/insert-numbers)`